# using Nginx as reverse proxy to apache or stand alone

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've read a lot about this issue (including all threads in this site) and couldn't come to a conclusive decision.

What is considered better (performance and security wise) for very high load sites (millions of users per day):

1. standalone Nginx + PHP + SQL
2. Nginx as a revers proxy for Apache + PHP + SQL

What I don't get is - if Nginx can run dynamic content why use Apache at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have 20+ web servers running `nginx+php-fpm` behind a pair of HAProxy balancers. In my opinion, and from my own experience, this is the optimal setup. Not taking anything away from Apache (I use it for over 10 years), but Nginx simply blows its socks off.

HAProxy is the best open source load balancer. Period. I have tried many, including commercial offerings. I installed nginx on the load balancer as well to offload the SSL. It works like a charm, even under high load.

Splitting all the static content (images, css, js, etc) to separate nginx(s) gives you a further performance boost. HAProxy can send all static requests to a separate server, meaning you have the benefit of parallel requests in your back end systems.

If you do try `HAProxy`, remember to keep the `MAXCONN` setting for the web servers to a low (like 20 of 40) value. I see so many posts that have the web server maxconn setting being set to something like 1000 - which will result in HAProxy overloading a node in no time flat.

Comment: wow great answer!! i think i got what i needed :)

Comment: No sweat. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use Apache-specific features there is no point in using it behind Nginx.

Comment: Thx, can you think of any Apache specific features i might be missing / need for my app?

Comment: There are over 500 Apache modules that provide loads of different functions and vast majority of the less popular ones don't have Nginx equivalent. See complete list here: https://modules.apache.org/search.php?query=true